# Visual Studio error list is not complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This problem annoys me for quite some time, it started back in VS 2012 and survived a complete reinstall of the computer, switching from Win7 to Win8.1 and from VS2012 to VS2013.

As of now, my compile fails with 50+ warnings and 5 errors in Output window, but only 3 warnings (and zero errors) are shown in Error list. (All 50+ warnings are generated by `[Obsolete("Reason")]` directives in the code.)

Why are the errors not shown in the error list? My filters are set to

```
Error list - Current Project (WebAPI)
0 of 0 Errors | 3 of 3 Warnings | 0 of 0 Messages
```

"Current project" is exactly what I am trying to compile. The errors are type casting errors and/or missing parameters in exactly that project. The project is of type "ASP.NET Web application (C#)"

I helped myself by scrolling through all the warnings in the output log just to find the few errors, but this is error-prone and time-consuming. Solving all `Obsolete` warnings just now is no option either (and this won't bring me back my handy error list, it will just reduce the size of the output log so I can sift through it faster after the compile has failed).

Comment: You may want to raise this as a possible bug with the VS dev team at MS

Comment: Did you try to use "#pragma warning disable 612, 618" and "#pragma warning restore 612, 618" to get rid of the warning messages for obsolate methods?

Comment: @HABJAN no, where would I put them?

Comment: @Alexander : you can do that on global level. Project properties->Build->(Errors and warnings) Suppress Warnings and then specify a comma separated list of warnings which need to be suppressed. In your case 612,618

Comment: @dotnetnewb eventually I will, but before I do that, I want to make sure that this is a bug, and not a misconfiguration in the project.